# JEXCelAPI on android

Tags: android, excel

When I added the JExcelAPI http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/ to the
class path and run my app, I get:
trouble writing output: shouldn't happen
[`2009-07-16 14:32:19 - xxx`] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with
error 2

any idea?
thanks

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200688/android-and-ioexception-strange-error

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error on android when using the example tutorial code from jexcelapi site.
E.g http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/tutorial.html

The fix for me was to replace the CellType in the right hand side of the comparison with cell:

For example, change:

```
if(a1.getType() == CellType.LABEL)
```

To this:

```
if(a1.getType() == cell.LABEL)
```

Where cell is populated with the sheet.getCell( ... ) api:

```
Cell cell = sheet.getCell(j, i);
```

Hope this helps!